# Paginación en Laravel por medio de un arreglo

Tags: sql, laravel-5, paginación

Quisiera saber cómo se realiza la paginación por medio de un array.

Este código que estoy realizado, hace lo siguiente: Realiza la consulta SQL en tiempo real por medio de un input, y el resultado de la consulta es añadido a una tabla, por lo que falta es que tenga paginación.

**.blade.php**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 fetch_customer_data();

 function fetch_customer_data(query = '')
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"{{ route('inv_bajas.action') }}",
   method:'GET',
   data:{query:query},
   dataType:'json',
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('tbody').html(data.table_data);
    $('#total_records').text(data.total_data);
   }
  })
 }

 $(document).on('keyup', '#search', function(){
  var query = $(this).val();
  fetch_customer_data(query);
 });
});
```

**Controller**

```
function action(Request $request)
    {
      if($request->ajax())
    {
     $output = '';
     $query = $request->get('query');

     if($query != '')
     {
       $data = DB::table('materials')
            ->where('marca','LIKE', '%'.$query.'%')
            ->orWhere('descripcion','LIKE', '%'.$query.'%')
            ->orWhere('tipo','LIKE', '%'.$query.'%')
            ->orderBy('folio', 'desc')
            ->get();
     }
     else
     {
      $data = DB::table('materials')
          ->orderBy('folio', 'desc')
          ->get();
     }
     $total_row = $data->count();
     if($total_row > 0)
     {
      foreach($data as $row)
      {
       $output .= '
       <tr>
             <td>'.$row->folio.'</td>
             <td>'.$row->marca.'</td>
             <td>'.$row->descripcion.'</td>
             <td>'.$row->tipo.'</td>
             <td>
                 <div class="form-check">
                     <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
                     <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1"></label>
                 </div>
             </td>
       </tr>
       ';
      }
     }
     $data = array(
      'table_data'  => $output,
      'total_data'  => $total_row
     );

     echo json_encode($data);
    }
    }
```

Comment: No acabo de entender lo que pides. ¿Laravel no tiene un sistema de paginación ya 'incluido'?

Comment: Creo que deberías ver una mejor manera de hacerlo te recomiendo usar **DataTables** con la opción Ajax sourced data para traer los datos desde el controlador en formato JSON y usar la tabla en la vista es decir en el archivo .blade, y esto te soluciona lo de la paginación espero te sirva.